# SQL: how to check if column contains letters in it

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

So basically i have an ic column in my db:
ic only contains numbers but the field is a string so people can add passport also.
i want to write a query where it only shows me ic which are only numbers:

```
SELECT applications.ic
FROM applications
WHERE applications LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

But it dosent work!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PostgreSQL [supports](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE) POSIX regular expressions:

```
SELECT applications.ic
FROM applications
WHERE applications.ic ~ '^\d+$'
```

The regular expression here is:

- `^` — matches the beginning of the string
- `\d` — matches a digit
- `+` — one or more modifier applied to the previous matcher
- `$` — matches the end of the string